# How to not close an HttpsURLConnectios after writing or reading DataStream

Tags: java, http, url, httpconnection, bufferedinputstream

how could I get connection alive after follows operation in Java:

```
private static void makePostRequestAndPrintContent(String payload) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    URL url = new URL("url");
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");   
    try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream())){
        wr.write(convertPayloadToBytes(payload));
    }

    printContent(con);

}
```

printcontent():

```
private static void printContent(HttpsURLConnection con) throws InterruptedException{

    if(con!=null){
    try {
       System.out.println("****** Content of the URL ********");
       String input;
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
       while ((input = br.readLine()) != null){
          System.out.println(input);     
       } 
       br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

After posting the payload I have to wait some time for PUT-response from the Server, but after execution of post-request and reading content from redirect-site, connection will be immediately closed (at least an app will be terminated). 
How to set connection to wait for further responses and then read InputStream again?